# CPP chrony io Code Freezes on one computer but not the other

Tags: c++, io, popen, rhel, timing

I am running the same cpp code on two identical computers, but it freezes on one computer only. I noticed that it only freezes when I add the below code call in one of the functions. I have no idea why. I even rewrote the code to try to fix it to no success. Whats even odder is that it will freeze at random times/spots (during the main or within the call, etc.). Any idea why?

I tried searching here to no success. Its not the computer architecture, and I don't believe there are memory leaks since it works on another computer just fine (thats identical aside from location and ip)

(Its not my { and } placement. I'm just having trouble getting it to paste as code for some reason)

```
void ntpSync(){

FILE *jitter;
char line[41];
char *start;    

jitter = popen("chronyc sources |cat", "r");

fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);
fgets(line,41,jitter);

start = strchr(line,'+');

myfile<<start;

pclose(jitter);
}
```

previously it was more elegant and was this (I was looking at a different value later). Regardless, both freeze on one computer and not the other

```
void ntpSync(){

FILE *fp;
char var[40];
char *nextSys;
char *sysTime;

fp = popen("chronyc tracking |cat", "r");

while (!feof(fp))
{
    while(fgets(var,40, fp)!=NULL)
    {   
        
        if(strncmp(var,"System time",11)==0)
        {
            nextSys = strtok(var,": ");
            while(nextSys != NULL)
            {
                if(strspn(nextSys,"seconds")==7)
                {           
                    myfile<<sysTime<<",";
                    break;
                }
                sysTime=nextSys;
                nextSys=strtok(NULL,": ");
                
            }
        }
}
```

Is maybe my chrony on one computer messed up and i should reinstall it? The "chronyc sources" call works on both in terminal and it fills my csv in my code.

Comment: So, not running the same code. Much less of a mystery. "Working" doesn't mean that there aren't memory leaks, either. This also doesn't look much like C++. Recommend removing that tag.

Comment: @sweenish theyre running the same code (I was probably just not clear in my wording). I switched/rewrote the call to make it the top (it was the bottom prior), but both freeze on one computer only (I ran both on each of the computers). 
Also, its CPP/C++. IIRC, only cpp can use labviews C API (I'm using labview in the main but that works).
Also, if there are memory leaks, should the other computer freeze too then? They're identical computers (essentially images of one another)

Comment: Where does it freeze/hang?  Have you run it under a debugger?

Comment: @G.M. it freezes randomly. I'm calling it in a while loop. Each iteration is a second long and it'll freezes on the 100th iteration, 1105th iteration, 400th iteration, etc. It also freezes randomly where in the code in that it will freeze when its writing different columns of the csv and not consistently in one spot. Its purely unpredictable when itll freeze, but it always freezes before the runs over.